# Creating a bubble-style marker in GMLIB

Tags: gmlib

I'm trying to set up a custom marker style for all of my markers. What I am trying to do looks like [this example](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-cgCJJYjsHN0/TgCbnq9_XOI/AAAAAAAAA8A/7sga1wRsGd8/s1600/photo2.PNG). So each marker has text in it. (All will be the same style, but with different colors and text set programmatically.) The type TStyledMarker is available but the TStyledIcon type seems not to exist. I did see a note in the source but I didn't understand whether it is implemented in another way.

How can I create these "siBubble" styled markers?

Thanks very much.

Comment: To use StyledMarker, you need to define TMarker.MarkerType = mtStyledMarker and TMarker.StyledMarker.StyledIcon = siBubble. You can define too the TMarker.StyledMarker.BackGroundColor and TMarker.StyledMarker.TextColor

Comment: Ah - found mtStyledMarker and siBubble in GMConstants. I don't see how to use the MarkerOptions, Icons, and Shapes as in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MarkerOptions in the GMLib. If this is possible, some examples would be great.

Comment: these properties are not implemented in GMLib yet